# Android: runtime exception database already closed

Tags: android

I'm using SQLite database for getting record of table where if specific record is exist.Always getting error while run the application = **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.example.tazeen.xxx/databases/xx(conn# 0) already closed**

```
 dbhelper = new MyDbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db1 = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db1.rawQuery("select * from ActivityObjectList", null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                imageName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("imageaudioPath"));
                String strDownLoadStatus = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DownLoad_Status"));
 } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();

       db1.close();
    }
```

Comment: Create DB instance on Application Level

Comment: can u tell on which line the exception is throwing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should close some thing like dbhelper.close()... instead of db1.close();

It's guess by understanding your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You should close your sqlite db object in db helper class

```
@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (mDb != null)
        mDb.close();

    super.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should close sqlite database after read the table.
you would use 
like this

Try{
 enter code here
 `what do to
}
finally{
db.close();`
}